# MS Teams outgoing webhook application

Tags: c#, botframework, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have built a bot in Visual Studio using C#, which I have registered with the Bot framework. Its a test bot at the moment, which merely scans the incoming text and returns a message on how many characters are in the message. However, what I want to do is to hook this bot up to a Teams channel and use some sort of trigger (similar to slash commands in Slack) and then take the text from the message and send that to my bot, which will then run some code to forward that data on to an external URL, which would then reply back to the bot and then forward that data into the Teams channel. Does anyone know if something like this is possible? At the least all I need to know is whether I can get some functionality similar to slash commands in Slack, which I can then work with and get the desired outcome from this bot.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the issue with Microsoft Teams bots that you either need to talk to them in 101 or mentioned them in a group conversation.
Secondly, the Slack-like commands are not supported and you need to understand the intent of a person. You can use buttons on cards instead.

It can be done in a few ways. The main idea is the following.
Bot: Hello, my name is Pradeep Patel. You can use me like "@pradeep launch ", where what is a parameter for launch command.
User: @pradeep launch rocket
Bot: User, the rocket has been launched.
User: @pradeep try jump
Bot: Sorry, I don't have the command "try" implemented. Please type "help" to find out more information.

You can use multiple tools to recognize intents:

- RegEx
- Google Api.ai
- Microsoft LUIS